# Sensor Tranfer Function

Tags: sensor, circuit-analysis, transfer-function, pid-controller

I've this transfermodel, my controller is a PID-controller and my sensor is [this](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/grove-rotary-angle-sensor-p-770.html?cPath=156_160), how can I find the Tranfer Function of the sensor?:

[image]

Comment: Is the purpose of your system to control a motor, and you want to use this angle sensor for feedback?

Comment: I've a stability system with motors to make it stabel and the sensor is to find the error in the angle that has to be 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a proper datasheet for the part you listed, but you can figure out the transfer function from a code example on the wiki page here: http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_Rotary_Angle_Sensor

```
int getDegree()
{
    int sensor_value = analogRead(ROTARY_ANGLE_SENSOR);
    float voltage;
    voltage = (float)sensor_value*ADC_REF/1023;
    float degrees = (voltage*FULL_ANGLE)/GROVE_VCC;
    return degrees;
}
```

The code implements the inverse transfer function of the sensor followed by the ADC.  So it looks like the sensor's transfer function of angle to voltage is:

$$V_{out}(\theta) = V_{DD} * \frac{\theta}{300°}$$

If you are connecting this to a 10-bit ADC like they are, you might also need the ADC's transfer function.  Assuming \$V_{ref} = V_{DD}\$, that transfer function is:

$$\text{Code out} = 1023 \cdot \frac{V_{in}}{V_{DD}}$$

Comment: Which one shout I use in my mathematical model? Is Vdd the same as Vin (I've to find Vout/Vin)

Comment: No, you are not supposed to find Vout/Vin in general.  Your system output is not a voltage, but an angle or possibly some other mechanical quantity.  Are you providing a voltage to a motor? In that case, you need to include the transfer function of the motor and other mechanical parts in your system.  Vdd is the supply voltage, probably 5V.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the transfer function of a system (whether it be a motor, sensor or control plant) experimentally by recording the inputs and outputs and then use system identification theory to find the transfer function. You need to know if your plant\sensor is behaving linearly so you can use linear system theory to design a plant. Some sensors and systems are not linear and then the math is much more complicated or you have to 'force' them to be linear with some kind of function. You may be able to determine how the sensor is behaving non-experimentally, a lot of sensors have frequency cutoffs that are one pole and behave as low pass filters. You can apply circuit theory and find a sufficient model for the sensor in other cases. Digital systems are a bit different I won't go into that here.

Your rotational sensor has a frequency cut-off and a delay, can you drive it infinitely fast and still measure the rotation? No, it has a rating, after a certian speed it is going to alias\stop switching or break. This needs to be factored in when modeling controls.